# Make a model (prototype) view xcode swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

Hi I am looking for way to make a model view. Similar to when you have a prototype cell but a for table but for a view that encapsulates imageviews and labels.

Is this possible to do with a view. I want to be able to create a view prototype on a second part of the storyboard and use it (and populate the imagevies ect in it) in my main viewcontroller.

An example of what I am trying to do is below:

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why table or collection don't suit you ?

Comment: Because it is not a table

Comment: cant you just create prototype DATA and populated it in your real view instead of create a total new prototype view?

Comment: @Tj3n No because I have one view set  underneath another view set. When I try to do that with views they combine inside each other, if I try to do it container it requires a viewccontroller for each of the containers.

Comment: Maybe some images and code would help, its really hard to imagine what you want to achieve in this

Comment: @Tj3n I made a sketch of what I am trying to do

Comment: Seems like they look the same, so you can just actually create 2 instance of that view and change the data which is the imageView's image, and the label string? And then put it in the VC?

Comment: They are not the same.

Comment: You cannot place view in storyboard outside the UIViewController, so for modelling your data better use another program. Otherwise, you can place as many views as you want in xib files for testing. However, I still confused about what you really going to do...

Comment: @IgorKislyuk It is a card that flips. Images on both sides. but trying to put the views on top of each other is problematic.

Comment: Well, it becomes much easier. You have got two choices: made custom transition from this view to itself, using UIView `transitionFromView:toView:durations:options:completion` or specify custom transitions between UIViewControllers

Comment: @IgorKislyuk Thanks for that

Comment: @NicholasMuir, no problem. Don't forget to help another

Comment: @IgorKislyuk I did that but it doesn't just flip the view. It flips the whole screen? Do you know why it would do that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use method like this to specify your view to made an animation

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewToFlip: UIView!

@IBAction func actionFlipView(sender: AnyObject) { 
    // don't forget to specify your options
    UIView.transitionWithView(viewToFlip, duration: 2.0, options: .TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: { 
        // set here any specific animation
        }) { (finished) in
            //here should be final steps for you animation
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can use method like this for customise you animation precisely.
`UIView.animateKeyFramesWithDuration(_:delay:options:animations:completion)`

Hope this may help you.